# How to avoid geom_line drawing over a text annotation?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a plot where I have points, lines and annotations in at each point. The problem is that lines end up passing through the annotation text and I'd like to find a solution to avoid that e.g. how to make the annotation be "on top"?

My pseudo ggplot is like:

```
# some df
ggplot(df,aes(x=x,y=y)) + geom_line() + geom_point() + 
   annotate('text', ...)
```

Note that if I swap the order of `geom_line` and `geom_point` the line will draw on top of the point (when color is not black of course or there is transparency). However, the line will draw right through the annotation text.

How can I fix that? so far I have chosen not to include lines but would be nice.

Comment: Please provide a _minimal_ example to illustrate your issue and for people to play around with.

Comment: `position = "dodge"` may help you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Probably the best option is to use `geom_label`, which will put a white background underneath the label text, covering the line (if placed after `geom_line`). The advantage of this is that the white background will be sized to blank out exactly that portion of the line that would go through the label.

If you have a single label, as in the `annotate` code below, you can use `geom_label` alone. However, if you have multiple labels that might overlap, you need two calls, one to `geom_label` with `colour="white"` to generate blank "labels" that are just there to cover the line, followed by a call to `geom_text` for the labels themselves. This is because the label backgrounds will overlap and obscure the text of overlapping labels when `geom_label` is used alone.

```
library(tidyverse)
theme_set(theme_classic())

ggplot(mtcars[1:20,], aes(wt, mpg)) + 
  geom_line() +
  geom_label(aes(label=round(mpg,2)), colour="white", label.padding=unit(0.05,"lines"), 
             size=3) +
  geom_text(aes(label=round(mpg,2)), size=3) +
  annotate("label", 2.25, 27, label="Label", colour="red", label.size=0)
```

In the code above, `label.size=0` gets rid of the border around the label.

[image]

Another option is to put a square white point marker under the annotation but on top of the line:

```
ggplot(mtcars[1:20,], aes(wt, mpg)) + 
  geom_line() +
  geom_point(shape=15, colour="white", size=6) +
  geom_text(aes(label=round(mpg,2)), size=3) +
  annotate("point", 2.25, 27, pch=15, size=7, colour="white") +
  annotate("text", 2.25, 27, label="Label", colour="red")
```

[image]

You could also make the lines less prominent. Below they just guide the eye, but don't intrude very much:

```
ggplot(mtcars[1:20,], aes(wt, mpg)) + 
  geom_line(linetype="11", colour="grey30", size=0.25) +
  geom_text(aes(label=round(mpg,2)), size=3) +
  annotate("text", 2.25, 27, label="Label", colour="red")
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice!! thank you so much for the throughout answer.

Comment: I've updated my answer to use `geom_label`, which probably the best option.